# How to use sshd_config - PermitUserEnvironment option

Tags: ssh

I have `client1` and `client2` both are Linux machines.
From `client1`:

```
client1$ssh root@client2 "env"
```

It displays list of ssh variables from `client2`.

Things I did on `client2`:

I want to add new variable to client2 . So I edited `sshd_config` to

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

and created a file environment under ssh with following entry

```
Hi=Hello
```

then restart sshd

```
/etc/init.d/sshd
```

---

Now from `client1` trying the same command

```
client1$ssh root@client2 "env"
```

didn't provide the new variable `Hi`.

ref:

- http://www.raphink.info/2008/09/forcing-environment-in-ssh.html
- http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/ssh/environment-variables-and-ssh.html/comment-page-1#comment-1703

Comment: done. "environement" file should be under ~/.ssh not under /etc/ssh
It's working fine.
Hope this somebody.

Comment: Not `/etc/ssh/environment` for sure, but `/etc/environment` should work (at least it does for me).

Answer (score 3):

> and created a file environment under
>   ssh with following entry Hi=Hello

You should create the file /root/.ssh/environment on client2, assuming that /root is the home directory of root.